# Angular and laravel infinte-scroll not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, laravel, infinite-scroll

Angular loads new pages just by moving the scroll bar. Not when it reaches the bottom. It even loads new posts when i scroll up.

```
app.factory('Recipes', function ($http) {
    var Recipes = function () {
        this.recipes = [];
        this.loading = false;
        this.page = 1;
    };

    Recipes.prototype.nextPage = function () {
        var url = 'api/recipes?page=' + this.page;
        if (this.loading) return;
        this.loading = true;
        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(this.page);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                    this.recipes.push(data.data[i]);
                }
                this.page++;
                this.loading = false;
            }.bind(this));
    };

    return Recipes;
});

app.controller('RecipesCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Recipes) {
    $scope.recipes = new Recipes();
});
```

This is the angular part. This is the laravel part:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
Route::get('recipes', [
    'as' => 'recipe.all',
    'uses' => 'RecipeController@recipes'
]);});
```

And this is the html part:

```
<div ng-controller="RecipesCtrl">
    <div class="recipe row" infinite-scroll="recipes.nextPage()" infinite-scroll-distance="1"
         infinite-scroll-disabled='recipes.loading'>
        <div ng-repeat="recipe in recipes.recipes | orderBy:sortOrder:sortReverse | limitTo:myLimit">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing your `infinite-scroll-distance` to a value closer to 0. Right now you are calling the API, when the bottom of the element is within 1000 pixels of the bottom of the browser.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But how do i stop it from loading more content when it reaches the bottom of the page ?

Comment: You don't - the directive is meant to infinitely load more content as you keep scrolling. Do you mean that you want it to stop when there is no more content?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant that it should stop loading when there is no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Problem: Why does infinite-scroll load more content constantly?**

`infinite-scroll-distance` is set to `1` in your code. This means that when the element is within 1000 pixels of the browsers bottom the directive will fetch more data.

If you change this to a value closer to 0, the user will have to scroll further for the trigger to get activated.

**Second Problem: How do I prevent the directive from loading more content, when there is no more content to return?**

One solution to stopping the directive from continuously loading more data is by setting the `recipes.loading = true;` when the returned data is empty.

As such:

```
.success(function (data) {
                console.log(this.page);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                    this.recipes.push(data.data[i]);
                }
                this.page++;
                this.loading = false;
                recipes.loading = true; // This should prevent more code from being loaded.
            }
```